# using jpeg as a memory mapped file

Tags: jpeg, memory-mapped-files

I have a jpeg image 360x288 resolution.  It is stored on my server. This image can be updated randomly but in a sequential manner.

I upload the image via a web service as a byte array,  I then save it to an image/jpeg on my hard drive.

And it continues...

Now, I am curious as to whether using a memory mapped file would improve efficiency as I have read some where (and not recall where) that an image by default is already a memory mapped file?

Any info would be great...

Comment: If that's 360x268 **in pixels** then it's really small. Memory mapped files are for really large files, with contents that do not fit in memory all at once.

Comment: Also: What efficiency do you want to improve? Upload/Download? Its unclear what you are doing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. So, will this not help me if I was updating that image say 2 times a second?

Comment: @Mathias Hi, sorry for the delay.  I am saving to hard drive so it is just the number of times i am saving an image the hard drive a second that i am mindful of.

Comment: Still unclear what you are doing. Exactly describe your workflow and where the bottleneck is. Although this has not much to do with this question anymore since merceln already gave a negative answer to that.

Comment: Hi, this image on my hard drive is 1 image. I want to update the contents of that image for latter retrieval.  I am assuming that constantly saving an image to a hard drive can cause unnecessary memory issues?  This app will be running 24/7. The image will be updated at least once a second.  So, my understanding is (and is probably wrong) that a memorymapped file is like a pointer to that image on the hard drive and that I do not have to open/overwrite all the time but just keep the pointer open?